# I want to copy files from a folder when they fell in to that folder using Java

Tags: java, watchservice

1. I want to copy files form my download folder (mostly text and some folders)to some specific folder when download  gets completed.
2. I want generate a text file which shows info about downloaded/created files.

I used watch service to monitor that folder and I have written code for copying files. It didn't work.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class HiddenProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try (WatchService Service = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()){
            Map<WatchKey, Path> KeyMap = new HashMap<>();
            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Pranu\\Downloads");
            KeyMap.put(path.register(Service,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY),
                    path);

        WatchKey watchkey;
         do {
            watchkey = Service.take();
            Path eventDir = KeyMap.get(watchkey);

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchkey.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();
                Path eventPath = (Path)event.context();
                System.out.println(eventDir + ":" + kind + " :" + eventPath);

            }
        } while (watchkey.reset());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ///TODO: handle Exception
        }
    }


    {   

        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

        try {

            File act1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Praveen\\Downloads\\");
            File act2 = new File("C:\\files\\");

            inStream = new FileInputStream(act1);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(act2);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            //delete the original file
            //act1.delete();

            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You dropped some requirements and some code. And what is your question?

Comment: On what operating system are you testing? Since from my knoweledge the FileSystem WatchService is not supported for all OS. Meaning a fail-safe option would be the active way. E.g. loop till you find something.

Comment: @n247s I would ask you to back your statement with some credible source. The "core" source https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#concerns doesn't mention any OS specific restrictions though!

Comment: @GhostCat judging your source it doesnt indeed. which is suprising to me. a long time ago I was digging into this api as wel, finding poorly support based on the class documentation, although that might have been the native indexing support. Since that part is mentioned in the link you posted, (and what the mechanism was I was looking for)

Comment: @n247s Thanks for your suggestion. But upto watch service code is working fine problem with copying and all

Comment: @GhostCat  The link you given helps to me

Comment: Guys Still i am facing problems. Please help me